# How to clear "The following packages have unmet dependencies" error on Ubuntu without changing anything

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I am trying to install something new on a server with apt-get and am getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cassandra : Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not installable
             Recommends: ntp but it is not going to be installed or time-daemon
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Everything I have found on the net so far advises upgrading/uninstalling Cassandra. I definitely can't do that! How can I get this error to go away without messing with Cassandra? I don't mind if I can't upgrade it afterwords using the package manager.

Is there a way to remove the package but leave all its files in place?

Comment: What happens if you try `apt-get install python-support` ?

Comment: It might be a better solution to add `python-support` to `/var/lib/dpkg/status` then at least all the cassandra files will still be protected against modification and may receive config updates etc.

Comment: Did you install cassandra from the wrong Ubuntu version? That's the usual cause of the problem.

Comment: I tried installing python-support got `Package python-support is not available`. So I edited /var/lib/dpkg/status and removed the dependency on python-support from cassandra. That worked and I was able to install new stuff! Tx guys. @user188737 you should answer my question so I can tick it.

Comment: Ok. I tried changing the conflict settings in /var/lib/dpkg/status and that didn't seem to work, deleting or adding a package did. It seems that dependency changes here work. I will check that out on my Ubuntu also and formulate an answer. Of course, if cassandra is updated, then the missing dependency problem will reappear.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy python-support` show I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* manipulate the **dpkg** package management system by hand editing its database of packages in one of the possible installed states: `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. It is quite human friendly readable. Each package in its own block with empty lines in between. Each block can specify **Depends**, **Conflicts**, **Breaks**, **Provides**, **Replaces** type of lines, which are parsed by dpkg to get a view of the tree of packages and install possibilities or problems.

Of course you should be beware of editing this file when **apt** or **dpkg** programs are running. Stopping the **unattended-upgrades** service could also be important. And also realize that your edits are **lost** when a package that you edited is up/downgraded replaced by alternatives or from another repository.

In this case it is possible to remove the `python-support` package from the **Depends:** line of the **cassandra** package and then dpkg has no missing dependency anymore.

You can also put a Hold marker on the cassandra package to stop it and its **status** entry from being overwritten accidentally or unattended: `apt-mark hold cassandra`

Other possibilities would be removing the **cassandra** package from the **status** database. But that would make it vulnerable for missing upgrades to other packages that make it non-functional. Its files would be left alone, and there may be trigger scripts that are triggered by other package configurations.

Or you could add a fake **python-support** package. Of course that would be dangerous if some other program is installed later on that really depends on it.

Some more apt tricks:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161940